# What is the difference between iterating map in the below ways?

Tags: java, iterator, treemap

I have a array of `String` which has few words and I'm trying to find the most frequent (number of occurrences) words of `k` from the given array. I also have a constraint that consider the most frequent words are of frequency `2` then I need to consider the one which comes first in alphabetical order then the next ones.

I created a `TreeMap` to hold the words vs it's frequency count. Now the keys (ie' words) in the map would be sorted alphabetically. Now I was trying to sort the map based on it's values with the following snippet.

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> Map<K, V> 
sortByValues(final Map<K, V> map) {
    Comparator<K> valueComparator = 
            new Comparator<K>() {
        public int compare(K k1, K k2) {
            int compare = 
                    map.get(k2).compareTo(map.get(k1));
            if (compare == 0) 
                return 1;
            else 
                return compare;
        }
    };

    Map<K, V> sortedByValues = 
            new TreeMap<K, V>(valueComparator);
    sortedByValues.putAll(map);
    return sortedByValues;
}
```

Now I'm iterating the map in the following ways,

**Method1**

```
Map sortedMap = sortByValues(map);
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
    if (k-- <= 0) {
        return result;
    }
    result.add(entry.getKey());
}
```

**Method2**

```
Map sortedMap = sortByValues(map);
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
// Get a set of the entries on the sorted map
Set set = sortedMap.entrySet();
 
// Get an iterator
Iterator i = set.iterator();
 
// Display elements
while(i.hasNext()) {
    if (k-- <= 0) {
        return result;
    }
        
    Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
    result.add((String) me.getKey());
}
```

Consider the following content in `TreeMap` initially,

```
// Put elements to the map
treemap.put("love", 2);
treemap.put("i", 2);
treemap.put("coding", 1);
```

**Method1** returns `["coding","i"]` as output whereas **Method2** way of iterating gives me `["i","love"]`.

#### Doubts

1. I'm confused with the two ways of iterating the map?
2. If I sort the `TreeMap` which is already sorted based on keys, if i sort again based by values will the sorting by keys be retained for equal value elements?

Comment: In method 1 you are using the original map, not the sorted map

Comment: Oh sorry ! that's the mistake. You pointed it right. Thank you. I suspected on the way I'm doing the iteration logic. My bad..